# Why is this wrapper for SynchronizedList thread safe?

Tags: java, concurrency

I am reading "Java Concurrency in Practice" and this case is a little bit unclear to me. Why is this code ThreadSafe?

```
@ThreadSafe
public class ListHelper<E> {
    public List<E> list =
        Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<E>());
    ...
    public boolean putIfAbsent(E x) {
        synchronized (list)  {
            boolean absent = !list.contains(x);
            if (absent)
} }
}
```

we lock instance of  `SynchronizedList`  list but inside that used inner object
`final Object mutex;     // Object on which to synchronize`

```
  public void add(int index, E element) {
            synchronized (mutex) {list.add(index, element);}
        }
```

We still have locks on two different objects. Why is it safe?

Comment: This code is not syntactically valid; you have a line `if (absent)` which is not followed by a statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question.
You have to follow the whole chain of when mutex is assigned.

If not specified explicitly when calling `Collections.synchronizedList` as a second argument it *will* be the list itself.

Deep down you eventully find this:

```
mutex = this;
```

Comment: oh, I missed that. What about cases when final `Object mutex = new Object();` ?

Comment: If you chosoe to use another mutex when creating the synchronized list (2 arg method) you would need to use that variable (mutex) instead of the list indeed.

Comment: But what about the case, when you have class, which has inside private `private Object mutex = new Object();` is it possible to do that safe way?

Comment: Other than using another additional external mutex (all the time) or accessing that private field with reflection and using that, no.